# Conversion from Propositional Logic to Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I came across a proposition which I'm having a hard time converting into predicate logic. It has been a long while since I have touched the topic.

The proposition reads

> \begin{align}
> &\text{Socrates is a human}\\
> &\text{Socrates is mortal}\\
> &\text{Therefore, some humans are mortal}
> \end{align}

Using predicate logic, I'd set this up as

> \begin{align}
> &P(s)\\
> &M(s)\\
> &\exists x\hspace{0.1cm} (P(x) \land M(x))
> \end{align}

which can be written as,

$$P(s) \land M(s) \rightarrow \exists x\hspace{0.1cm} (P(x) \land M(x))$$

However, I feel like this is incorrect. Could someone suggest how to better represent this proposition using predicate logic?

Comment: Please replace in the conclusion $H(x)$ with $M(x)$.

Comment: Wuth the typo removed, the translation is correct.

Comment: … With the provision that $x$ does not occur free within either premise.

Comment: Nitpicking issue ... You are not "converting from propositional logic..."; you are symbolizing (expressing) some propositions in predicate logic :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to put these three statements into one statement. A statement is different from an argument. To indicate you are dealing with an argument, you can use the $\therefore$ symbol. So, I would symbolize this argument as: \begin{align}
&P(s)\\
&M(s)\\
&\therefore \exists x\hspace{0.1cm} (P(x) \land M(x))
\end{align}