# Proofs with predicates and syllogism

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Need some help with this question.

Prove that the following syllogism is valid by following the steps below.

```
My teapot is purple
My teapot holds water
--------------------
There exist purple things that hold water
```

a) Translate the syllogism into set-theoretic notation

```
        x∈A
       (x∈B)
      -------
      (A∩B≠∅) or (C∩B≠∅)??
```

b) Translate your set-theoretic notation into the notation of predicate logic

```
         x∈A
         x∈B
        -----
      ∃y∈Ay∈B ??
```

c) Give a proof that the syllogism is valid, similar to that given in the lecture 5 videos.

```
      S = A
      p(y)=y∈B
      p(x)∧(x∈S)⊨∃y∈Sp(y)
      S≠∅ ↔ ∃x∈U x∈S

  /** curious as to what this final question is actually looking for? **/
```

I would really appreciate any hints or feedback.

Comment: See the post [conversion-from-propositional-logic-to-predicate-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182206/conversion-from-propositional-logic-to-predicate-logic)

Answer (score 1):

This answer will symbolize "my teapot" as $t$ which is the name of a particular object in the domain of "things". I will use $x$ as a variable for an unspecified object in this domain. I will symbolize "purple things" as $P$ and "things that hold water" as $H$.

Here is the syllogism:

```
My teapot is purple
My teapot holds water
--------------------
There exist purple things that hold water
```

Here is a formulation in set-theoretic notation:

$t \in P$

$t \in H$

$P \cap H \neq \varnothing $

Here are two slightly different formulations in predicate logic:

$Pt$ or $P(t)$

$Ht$ or $H(t)$

$\exists x(Px \land Hx)$ or $\exists x(P(x) \land H(x))$

Using the notation of the first formulation, here is a proof presented in a [Fitch-style proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) to confirm its validity:

[image]

The inference rules used are conjunction introduction (∧I) and existential introduction (∃I).

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

For (a), the conclusion should be $A \cap  B \neq \varnothing $

For (b), I think you are expected to say:

$A(x)$

$B(x)$

--

$\exists y (A(y) \land B(y))$

For (c), (not sure what "lecture 5 videos" are, LOL) you have 
[Conjunction introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_introduction)
and
[Existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization). I think you are expected to write a proof tree of some sort. Maybe look in your textbook for examples, or follow the example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_of_a_proof).